# Best cantenna reflector type

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, antennas, radio-frequency

If the reflector (closed end) of [cantenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantenna) is shaped as parabolic dish, will it perform better than one with a flat reflector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not likely; what may help is that the can as a radiation source is shaped so that the phase fronts of the field leaving it is spherical. If the can's diameter is not larger than the wavelength, $d \approx \lambda$, then it will look to the parabolic dish as a point source if the dish's focal length is also several wavelengths and not much can be done anyhow. But if you are interested in shorter wavelengths relative to the can's diameter and try to shape the illumination and thereby reduce sidelobes then you may have to shape the can. In either case, $d \approx \lambda$ or $d > \lambda$, shaping *any* part of the can will affect your match to the coax cable and that is important, too, although it has no direct effect on the radiation pattern.